# Buckwheat groats have grassy smell?

Tags: food-safety, buckwheat

I bought some buckwheat groats recently. These are from a different source than where I normally get them, and I notice that these have a slightly grassy smell both before and after cooking. The other brand has a nuttier smell. They don't taste bad, but I want to see if this is normal and make sure there is nothing wrong with this batch of groats. I soak the groats overnight and then make them in a pressure cooker. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I won't comment on the safety of your buckwheat, but is it really so hard that it requires soaking and pressure cooking?  It's more typical to cook the raw or toasted groats in boiling water for just 15 minutes.

Comment: @Juhasz Most recipes I have found recommend soaking them overnight, so I just followed those. A stovetop method may work, I just haven't tried it that way yet.

Comment: Interesting that the recipes suggested that.  It couldn't hurt, except by wasting time.  I've found that overcooking kasha even a little, or adding a little too much water, makes it turn to mush.  So it's hard to imagine that soaking them would really make any kind of difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with them. The buckwheat is probably ok because on the on the official website called Anthony’s goods every single review is a five star( in fact one of the reviews called the grassy smell you talked about “natural”)one except one review which is four stars ( the four star review was because there was a rip in the package). Plus on the official store the buckwheat groats are sold out meaning people like them and want to buy them. Additionally all the other products on the store also are rated 5 stars. Here is a link to the official website (https://www.anthonysgoods.com/products/anthonys-usda-organic-raw-hulled-buckwheat-groats-grown-in-usa-5-pounds-5lb-certified-gluten-free?variant=1813269699)

Comment: Also If you tell me what brand it is I can give you more info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I typically buy from Whole Foods, but this brand is Anthony's.

Comment: @kmid5280 I edited my response. If it works for you consider marking it the “approved” one.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful! I appreciate your time and thoroughness. However the question was more about buckwheat in general rather than any specific brand. I'm not sure it was necessary to edit your response, particularly if this is something that could show up across different brands too.

Answer (score 0):

Well a grassy smell seems to be apt, seeing as grain is not that far removed from grass. Grain often being fed interchangeably for animals who eat grass. Typically grain does not need presoaking as it does not have a hard outer shell. Pretty soaking to me is done with beans for instance to soften the outer shell so as to make the cooking process smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. The Russian brands of Kasha have the nutty smell, and the American brands have the grassy or perfume smell. I wish the Russian brand was still affordable stateside, it was actually appealing.